# Programming Issue in my counting sort algo

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Please let me know the issue i have in this short code. I tried to follow the algo from the book and convert it into a program but have done some error in the process. Its throwing arrayoutofbounds exception

```
Algo which i tried to follow is bellow:

countingsort(a,b,k)
    1)let c[0..k] be a new array
    2)for i =0 to k
    3)   c[i]=0;
    4)for j=1 to a.length
    5)  c[a[j]]=c[a[j]]+1
    6)for i = i to k
         c[i] = c[i] + c[i-1]
    7)for j=a.length downto 1
         b[c[a[j]]]= a[j]
         c[a[j]] = c[a[j]]-1

public class CountingSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array_A = {6, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2};
        int[] array_B = new int[array_A.length];

        int k = 6;
        countingSort(array_A,array_B,k);
        //System.out.println(array_B);


    }
    public static void countingSort(int[] A, int[] B, int k){
        int[] C = new int[k+1];
        for(int i = 0; i<=k; i++){
            C[i] = 0;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j<A.length; j++){
            C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] + 1;

        }
        for(int i = 1; i<=k; i++){
            C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1];
        }
        for(int j = A.length-1; j>=1; j--){
            B[C[A[j]]] = A[j];
            C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] - 1;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(B));


    }

}

Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
    at importantPrograms.CountingSort.countingSort(CountingSort.java:22)
    at importantPrograms.CountingSort.main(CountingSort.java:11)
```

Comment: where is the issue? what is the question?

Comment: have updated the question. So sorry for the incomplete question earlier.

Comment: What is the algorithm given by the book? Might be easier to make sense of the logic with something to compare it to

Comment: have added the algo as well now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified code that worked for me.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class CountingSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array_A = {6, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2};
        int[] array_B = new int[array_A.length];
        int k = 6;
        countingSort(array_A,array_B,k);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array_B));
    }
    public static void countingSort(int[] A, int[] B, int k){
        int[] C = new int[k+1];
        for(int i = 0; i<=k; i++){
            C[i] = 0;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j<A.length; j++){
            C[A[j]] ++;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i<=k; i++){
            C[i] += C[i-1];
        }
        for(int j = A.length-1; j>=0; j--){
            B[--C[A[j]]] = A[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, instead of hard-coding the max value (6), you would find the max programmatically and size your count array accordingly. Such as

In main method

```
countingSort(array_A,array_B,max(array_A));
```

Max method

```
public int max(int[] arr){
    int m = 0;
    for(int i : arr){
        if(i>m){
            m = i;
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Did what you suggested. It still gives the same error.

Comment: @bhavishyatyagi After running and testing the code, I discovered that the error occurs in the final loop when you attempt to put everything in place. `C[6]` has a value of 11, which is the number of elements in the original array. since this is the case, the max index you should be using is 10. I updated my answer with the code that worked for me. Another option would be to insert as `B[C[A[j]]-1] = A[j]`;

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions and help. I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Change

1. `C[A[j]] = C[A[j] + 1];` to `C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] + 1;` because you are supposed to count the number of particular number occurrence.

Comment: Hey i have corrected that. But it still throws arrayoutofbounds

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what you are doing but there is only a little mistake in your second for loop. 
Change `j<A.length to j<C.length`